# Cannot access table cell on actions button click jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following table html:

```
<table>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class=" select-checkbox"></td>
        <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
        <td>Jonathan</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>jkname@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit" onclick="editUser();">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class=" select-checkbox"></td>
        <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
        <td>Cameron</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>camname@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit" onclick="editUser();">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my `editUser` function:

```
function editUser(){
    var id = jq(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
    alert(id);
}
```

It's not returning the id value from the 2nd cell

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jquery, bind an function and use this inside of it.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".edit", function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('.sorting_1').text();
  alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <table>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class=" select-checkbox"></td>
        <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
        <td>Jonathan</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>jkname@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class=" select-checkbox"></td>
        <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
        <td>Cameron</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>camname@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```